# Replace a token (put a comma before title case words)

Tags: python, nltk

I would like to put a comma before all words in title case. For that I tried with tokens:

```
text="Hey, I would like To Have a chocolate CAKE"
tokens=word_tokenize(text)
for word in tokens:
    if word.istitle():
          word="," + word
```

But nothing changes in `tokens`. Why?

Comment: Reassigning `word` **does not** affect `tokens`. Try `for index, word in enumerate(tokens):` then explicitly assign back to `tokens[index]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hmm, let me see if I can find a better one, this is a common question.

Comment: That looks like a good one... by the power of Asgard!!

Comment: @CoryKramer done and done